# Test if first two bits of hash are both 1

Tags: python, blockchain

For blockchain mining, I need to test whether the first two bits of a hash are both 1. I am using a Python library called [Simple-Python-Blockchain](https://github.com/howCodeORG/Simple-Python-Blockchain), which calculates a hash using the following method:

```py
    def hash(self):
        h = hashlib.sha256()
        h.update(
        str(self.nonce).encode('utf-8') +
        str(self.data).encode('utf-8') +
        str(self.previous_hash).encode('utf-8') +
        str(self.timestamp).encode('utf-8') +
        str(self.blockNo).encode('utf-8')
        )
        return h.hexdigest()
```

I tried this way:

```
str(int(block.hash(),16)).startswith("11")
```

Please help me understand what has to be done.

Comment: By "first two bits", do you mean the two most-significant bits, or the two least-significant bits? If you mean the most-significant bits, do you mean relative to a fixed number of bits for the hash, or relative to the highest 1 bit (i.e. the fewest bits needed to represent the number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash method in your question uses the SHA-256 algorithm, and returns the result as a hexadecimal string. To get the first two bits, we only need to look at the first hexadecimal digit, which encodes the first *four* bits:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> h = hashlib.sha256(b'Hello, world!')
>>> first_4_bits = int(h.hexdigest()[0], base=16)
3
```

The first *two* bits will be the upper two bits of this number, so we can right-shift by two places and then compare with the number 3, which is 11 in binary:

```py
>>> (first_4_bits >> 2) == 3
False
```

Alternatively, we can take advantage of the fact that only `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` in hexadecimal have 11 as their first two bits:

```py
>>> h.hexdigest()[0] >= 'c'
False
```

Comment: For the `int` version I'd suggest writing the second arg as a keyword argument like `base=16`, but that's just for clarity's sake.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on whether its the most significant or least significant change the substring. In the event it's a little endian and you want the most significant bits take that int, convert is to binary with `bin(<your_int>)` then you can take a substring with [2:4]. For example `bin(13)[2:4] == '11')`